# Websphere Application server not starting

Tags: websphere-6.1

**We have one Websphere Application server instance which went down with OutOfMemory and is not starting after that. The error message in the log below. Any urgent help will be highly appreciated. WAS version is 6.0.2.33**

03/04/13 14:16:01:536 BST] 0000000a WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
META-INF/ws-server-components.xml
[03/04/13 14:16:01:547 BST] 0000000a WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationError: com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationError: Problem initializing AdminImpl: 
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:180)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:568)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationError: Problem initializing AdminImpl: 
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.AdminImpl.initialize(AdminImpl.java:780)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponent(ContainerImpl.java:1160)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:1014)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.initialize(ServerImpl.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:173)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationWarning: Problem registering JVM MBean.
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.AdminImpl.initialize(AdminImpl.java:405)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: **ADMN0005E: The service is unable to activate MBean: type JVM, collaborator** com.ibm.ws.management.component.JVMMBean@6da65714, configuration ID JVM, descriptor null.
    at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.activateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.activateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:400)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.AdminImpl.initialize(AdminImpl.java:394)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.DescriptorParseException: ADMN0001W: The service is unable to parse the MBean descriptor file com/ibm/ws/management/descriptor/xml/JVM.xml.
    at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptor(MBeanDescriptorLoader.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorManager.loadDescriptorFile(MBeanDescriptorManager.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorManager.getDescriptor(MBeanDescriptorManager.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.activateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:427)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo.equals(MBeanNotificationInfo.java:155)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorLoader.addFeatures(MBeanDescriptorLoader.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorLoader.loadParentTypes(MBeanDescriptorLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorLoader.endDocument(MBeanDescriptorLoader.java:217)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptor(MBeanDescriptorLoader.java:155)
    ... 19 more

Answer (score 0):

I think your websphere is trying to use SUN JDK/JRE instead of IBM JDK/JRE.

Comment: Another instance in the same server running with same JDK

Comment: check the log files size. Delete them if too big.

Comment: @BhabaniShankar, did you figure out the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you can delete all instance of Websphere servers and then you need to restart it and synch the node , node agent before to check jdk version in your environment path in the WAS.